# How to receive ALL message types using MVVM Community Toolkit

Tags: c#, .net-core, toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a large C# app that I'm porting to .NET 6.  It uses a couple dozen different types of message, all of which are derived from my BaseMessage.  With MVVM Light, I was able to receive a copy of any of the messages (for testing and logging) by registering for  messages, but the Toolkit documentation explicitly states that the included
WeakReferenceMessenger can't do that.

I don't yet understand this new Messenger well enough to roll my own message handler (any examples would be gratefully received).  Can anyone suggest how to catch any message that goes by?

Meanwhile, I'm using the (ugly) method proposed in the Microsoft Learn Migrating from MvvmLight document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/migratingfrommvvmlight): registering individually for each possible message in both the tester and the logger.

Thanks